# Using moment.js to determine if current time (in hour) is between certain hours

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

I am working on a function that'd greet its users with a time-aware greeting (Good Morning, Afternoon, Evening, Night). Here's the script that I've made

```
import moment from "moment";

function generateGreetings(){
    if (moment().isBetween(3, 12, 'HH')){
        return "Good Morning";
    } else if (moment().isBetween(12, 15, 'HH')){
        return "Good Afternoon";
    }   else if (moment().isBetween(15, 20, 'HH')){
        return "Good Evening";
    } else if (moment().isBetween(20, 3, 'HH')){
        return "Good Night";
    } else {
        return "Hello"
    }
}

$("greet")
.css({
    display: "block",
    fontSize: "4vw",
    textAlign: "center",
    })
.text(generateGreetings() +", name")
```

But it simply wont work and just returns "Hello". I've also tried using

```
var currentTime = moment();
var currentHour = currentTime.hour();
```

and use `currentHour` to replace `moment()` inside the function but when I do so the site just dissapears.
Hoping anyone here has any insight on what I should do to fix this issue.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are using `moment().isBetween()` in a wrong way. You can see the correct method usage from [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/). For your requirement, no need to use this `isBetween` method. You can simply get the hour and then check it against the `if` condition.

You can re-arrange your method like below.

```
function generateGreetings(){

  var currentHour = moment().format("HH");

  if (currentHour >= 3 && currentHour < 12){
      return "Good Morning";
  } else if (currentHour >= 12 && currentHour < 15){
      return "Good Afternoon";
  }   else if (currentHour >= 15 && currentHour < 20){
      return "Good Evening";
  } else if (currentHour >= 20 || currentHour < 3){
      return "Good Night";
  } else {
      return "Hello"
  }

}
```

Comment: This works! Thanks a lot mate! I was using it that way because the example there used date directly so I thought it'll also work with hours.

Comment: @DavidBudiarto Glad to hear that. :)

Comment: For the Good Night you need to change the `&&` to `||`, I guess...

Answer (score 3):

@Thusitha

or you can use

```
moment().hour()
```

instead of

```
moment().format('HH')(
```

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer can be simplified a lot; the `elses` are completely superfluous because of the early returns:

```
function greeting() {
        const hour = moment().hour();

        if (hour > 16){
            return "Good evening";
        }

         if (hour > 11){
             return "Good afternoon";
         }

         return 'Good morning';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to split day times (Morning times and Evening times)

**Replace YYYY-MM-DD with the actual date you want to use:**

```
const date = moment("YYYY-MM-DD");
const morningEnd = moment(date).hour(12).minute(0).second(0);
const eveningStart = moment(date).hour(18).minute(0).second(0);

const morningTimes = [];
for (let m = moment(date); m.isBefore(morningEnd); m.add(30, 'minutes')) {
  morningTimes.push(m.format('HH:mm'));
}

const eveningTimes = [];
for (let m = eveningStart; m.isBefore(moment(date).endOf('day')); m.add(30, 'minutes')) {
  eveningTimes.push(m.format('HH:mm'));
}

console.log('Morning times:', morningTimes);
console.log('Evening times:', eveningTimes);
```